# How to update authentication token for a git remote?

Tags: command-line, git, gitlab

I revoked my token for [GitLab](https://gitlab.com), how can I set the new token for cmd use?

When trying to push, this is the error I get:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/myusername/repo.git'
```

The `credential.helper` is set to `manager`.

I tried to unset `credential.helper`, and then when I push it asked for the credentials, which will work when I supply them. If I re-set `credential.helper` to `manager`, it will raise the previous error again.

So, how can I set the new token?
(The preferred method would be from the cmd).

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a generic method that should work with all currently configured (and writable) credential helpers (and to be honest, I'm surprised git didn't do this automatically – it's *supposed* to):

1. Run `git credential reject` (to use all configured helpers) or `git credential-manager erase` (to use the `manager` helper).
2. Type in the following text:

   ```
   protocol=https
   host=gitlab.com
   path=/myusername/repo.git
   ```

   The main `git credential` tool also accepts a simpler version (but individual helpers do not):

   ```
   url=https://gitlab.com/myusername/repo.git
   ```
3. At a blank line, press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Windows Console) or <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> (Linux, Cygwin, macOS...) to signal end-of-input.
4. If you want, repeat with `git credential fill` or `git credential-manager get` to make sure the credentials cannot be retrieved anymore.

Comment: I already fixed it with my solution, but it seems that yours is the correct way, which I haven't found in my research. Thanks!

Comment: Did not work on windows 10. Manually removing from windows credential manager did https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541774/429476

Answer (score 20):

### CMD

With [cmdkey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey):

1. Run `cmdkey /list` from the command line, and find your target.
2. To update the password, run `cmdkey /generic:$TARGET_NAME$ /user:$MYUSERNAME$ /pass` and enter your password when prompted.

   - For example: `cmdkey /generic:git:https://gitlab.com /user:myusername /pass`
3. Use the credential again - push to your git remote.

### GUI

With [Windows Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager):

1. From the start menu, search and open the **Credential Manager**.

   - Or, run `control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager`
2. Go to the **Windows Credentials** section and find your relevant credential (e.g the git remote service, in this case - GitLab).
3. Open the credentials details.
4. Choose **Edit**
5. Enter the new password.
6. Save.
7. Use the credential again - push to your git remote.

[image]